# How to assign a dictionary to each of another dictionary's values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, append

I have two dictionaries which are related in content. One is formed from a data set taking the ***'shopid'*** as the **key** and taking ***'userid'*** as the **value**. The other dictionary is formed from the same data set but takes the ***'userid'*** as the **key** and the ***'datetime'*** of the purchases made by this user as the **value**.

What I would like to be able to do is to create a for loop (or similar) which, for each 'shopid' key takes the 'userid' values and turns those 'userid' values into the key that contains the 'datetime' values from the 2nd dictionary. This is for a large data set.

I understand that dictionaries have some restrictions on what you can do to them so it would be great to know if this is possible or if there is a better way of achieving a similar result?

As an example of input/output ideal:

```
dict1 = {'shopid1':['userid1','userid2','userid3']}
dict2 = {
    'userid1':['2020-08-17 09:00','2020-08-18 08:30'], 
    'userid2':['2020-08-16 11:00','2020-08-15 13:30'], 
    'userid3':['2020-08-18 09:30','2020-08-18 10:00','2020-08-18 11:30']
    }
    
combined_dict = {
    'shopid1':{
        'userid1':['2020-08-17 09:00','2020-08-18 08:30'],
        'userid2':['2020-08-16 11:00','2020-08-15 13:30'],
        'userid3':['2020-08-18 09:30','2020-08-18 10:00','2020-08-18 11:30']
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

The actual dictionaries I want to combine look like this:

```
shopid = {10159: [[[62775725, 214988798, 214988798, 214988798, 62775725, 
    62775725]]]
userid = {166840413: [[datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 29, 15, 48), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 29, 15, 48), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 29, 
    15, 48)]]
```

I believe the extraneous square brackets are a product of using default dict a few times to create new shortened dictionaries that have removed values that don't meet the requirements of the problem.

Comment: What is your high level goal of this exercise? What is the big picture? Have you ever used a `pandas.DataFrame`? You might find it useful.

Comment: The dictionary restriction is that their keys must be immutable / hashable. So keys that are strings, numbers, tuples of strings, etc are okay. Lists, iterators or other dictionaries as keys aren't allowed. 

So in this case all keys are strings! You're good to go, and just need to iterate over both dictionaries to build the one you want.

Comment: @Robert Overall goal is to find which users have made more than three purchases at a shop within an hour (order brushing problem taken from Kaggle). I have used a dataframe initially to access the data from a csv but in elimating the shops or users that do not meet the requirements thought it was a good option to make dictionaries - possibly I was wrong!

Comment: @bbbbbb Right, that makes sense. I have just edited my question to add in what my two dictionaries actually look like - would the multiple square brackets be the cause of my problem? I used Colin's answer below and it returned an empty dictionary for each shopid.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with dict comprehension:

```
combined_dict = {i: {j: dict2[j] for j in dict1[i]} for i in dict1}
```

Output:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> pp(combined_dict)
{'shopid1': {'userid1': ['2020-08-17 09:00', '2020-08-18 08:30'],
             'userid2': ['2020-08-16 11:00', '2020-08-15 13:30'],
             'userid3': ['2020-08-18 09:30',
                         '2020-08-18 10:00',
                         '2020-08-18 11:30']}}
```

Comment: If you are dealing with a large dataset then you should consider @Robert's comment and use a tool better suited for very large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for a "Comprehension" which is optimized to be considerably faster than looping:

```
combined_dict = { k:
            {u:t for (u,t) in dict2.items() if u in v}  
            for (k,v) in dict1.items()
            }
```

See here for detail: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: Thank you for this, I believe this is what I am looking for. Unfortunately due to the way I have organised my data in the previous code I have ended up with lists inside my dictionary keys. For instance dict1.items() returns: dict_items([(10159, [[[62775725, 214988798, 214988798, 214988798, 62775725, 62775725]]]). The same is true for dict2 although it only has two sets of square brackets around its values. I think this means I need to re-write my previous code! Printing combined_dict as it is now just returns the shopid key values with empty {} as the values.

Comment: I have figured out this is because of using defaultdict(list) to create my dictionaries. e.g. shops_dict = defaultdict(list)
for shop in shops: 
    shops_dict[shop].append(sData[shop])
shops_dict = dict(shops_dict). Unsure how to fix this, I have used similar for loops throughout my code to whittle down my data- any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'shopid1':['userid1','userid2','userid3']}
dict2 = {'userid1':['2020-08-17 09:00','2020-08-18 08:30'], 
'userid2':['2020-08-16 11:00','2020-08-15 13:30'], 
'userid3':['2020-08-18 09:30','2020-08-18 10:00','2020-08-18 11:30']}
combined_dict ={'shopid1':{'userid1':['2020-08-17 09:00','2020-08-18 08:30'],
'userid2':['2020-08-16 11:00','2020-08-15 13:30'],
'userid3':['2020-08-18 09:30','2020-08-18 10:00','2020-08-18 11:30']}}
for i in combined_dict:
    print(i)
    a=combined_dict[i]
    for j in a:
        b=a[j]
        print(j)
        for k in b:
            print(k)
```